# Best repository practices for packages

Tags: dtx

I have a repository with a package which I am satisfied with. It is laid out like so,

```
.
├── README.md
├── examples
│   ├── command1.tex
│   └── command2.tex
├── package.sty
├── command1.tex
└── command2.tex
```

Where `./command1.tex` is the implementation for `\command1`. Same goes for `./command2.tex`. `examples/` has examples for running the respective commands. `package.sty` simply `\input`s the other implementation files.

I would like to upload this package to CTAN, or at least generate `.dtx` and `.ins` files.

I have found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662997/best-practice-for-dtx-workflow) but am looking for a more specific answer?

Should I be reorganize my files into a single dtx? Should I make a build tool do that? If a build tool does it what build tool should I use? `sty2dtx` doesn't seem to like `\input`s. What exactly should my repository look like and what steps do I need to take to create the desired CTAN package format:

```
my-package.zip:
  my-package/
    README.md
    my-package.dtx
    my-package.ins
    my-package.pdf
```

Comment: Maybe start with reading l3build's documentation? Another option is to look at "popular" package's repository to see how they're organized.

Comment: There's also [How do I create a LaTeX package? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34175/how-do-i-create-a-latex-package)

Comment: Ah, I see you have left a comment under one of the answer in that link. To your specific question (instead of what is being written here): **you can upload a package consist of only a [.sty] file to CTAN** if you want to, as long as it has some accompanied (usually PDF) documentation (and source file used to generate such documentation). There's a few other things needed (e.g. all auxiliary files e.g. command1.tex etc. need to all start with your package's "unique prefix" so e.g. package-command1.tex, usually errors will resolve itself out after some mails with CTAN maintainers.

Comment: On that note see also [documentclass writing - What is good practice when preparing a package for CTAN? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25116/what-is-good-practice-when-preparing-a-package-for-ctan). (p/s personal opinion, but after a while writing `\__⟨package prefix⟩_` scattered everywhere in the .sty file gets tiring.)

Comment: note filenames need to be _globally_ unique so your package should be in one file or at least use a common prefix such as `package.sty`, `package-command1.tex` ,`package-command2.tex` ,

Comment: don't _generate_  the dtx, that is availble as a source format, but you do not have to use it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So, I would either 1. Provide a standalone pdf in addition to what I have _or_ 2. Convert what I have to `.dts`+`.ins`?

Comment: @user202729 ah, that second question seems very similar to mine. Perhaps I'm duplicating. I'll definitely check out `l3build`. Are there any packages I should reference in particular?

Comment: @Logan do either, you will see both styles  on ctan

Comment: Hm, not sure. But https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray is a particular package that does not use dtx.

Comment: tikz-pgf does not use dtx,

Comment: Ah ok, very cool. I think I have enough of to go off here. If I find something necessarily different from both [How do I create a LaTeX package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34175/how-do-i-create-a-latex-package) and [What is Good Practice... CTAN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25116/what-is-good-practice-when-preparing-a-package-for-ctan) then I will compile an answer for my own question. If I don't find anything necessarily unique, I will mark my question as duplicate with reference to both of those question. Thank you guys!

Comment: What about closing as duplicate anyway then post (anything new you might find) to one of the linked questions? That way people coming across the linked question (more likely since they're more popular) will be able to find your answer

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I've already flagged my own question as duplicate.

Comment: @Logan If you'd like to have the best of both worlds, a runable .sty file *and* keep documentation and code together, you could have a look at this answer by @ Phelype https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1861#a2092 I'm using this technique for the TikZlings package